# Does arithmetic on a random number reduce its entropy?

Tags: math, random, cryptography, entropy

For instance, as I was reading [this](http://betterexplained.com/articles/rethinking-arithmetic-a-visual-guide/) post on betterexplained.com, the author mentioned transforming a random number that lies in the range (0,1) to a random number that lies in the range (5,10) by multiplying and then adding by 5.

Do operations such as these decrease the entropy of the number? If so how/why? I understand that operations like floor or ceiling would decrease the entropy because information is lost. Information is also lost when we use the modulo operator, or even when we hash the number. Entropy should also be lost when squaring or taking the absolute value of a random number (obviously this doesn't apply to a number between 0 and 1), because the sign of the number is lost, and these operations cannot be undone.

Both of the functions applied to our initial number have inverses (/5 and -5, respectively), so information shouldn't be lost. But I can't help but think that it is, because of floating point approximations.

Please help me understand why my intuition is or is not the case, both with a theoretical random number of infinite precision, and the real world case.

Comment: Probably better asked at http://cs.stackexchange.com, almost certainly off-topic here.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I think this is more about IEEE specs on floating point values and how that relates to the calculated entropy of actual pseudorandom number generators on hardware. I don't think it belongs at the CS site -- more appropriate here.

Answer (score 3):

Using IEEE-754 format the following ranges have the same number of doubles:

```
   0.125-  0.25
   0.25 -  0.5
   0.5  -  1.0
   1.0  -  2.0
   2.0  -  4.0
   4.0  -  8.0
   8.0  - 16.0
```

Moreover, they are equidistant in each of these ranges.

From this it should be clear that there are many more doubles in the range 0 - 1 than there are in the range 5 - 10. Since 5 - 10 is 3/4 of one plus 1/4 of another range combined 5 - 10 has the same number of doubles as any of the ranges mentioned.

However, that doesn't settle it. You have to ask how the random number generator is generating numbers in the range 0 - 1. A simple way is to generate random numbers in the range 1 - 2 and then subtract one, taking advantage of the equidistance in the range 1 - 2. But there are other methods e.g. flip a coin if it is head map 1 - 2 to 0.5 - 1. If tails flip the coin again, if heads now, map 1 - 2 to 0.25 - 0.5, etc. This way you could generate pretty much any double in the range 0 - 1 (ignoring denormalized numbers) while maintaining uniformity.

Answer (score 1):

This is not true in theory (because these operations are invertible (more generally, because they are measurable isomorphisms)) but on a physical computer, due to floating point precision yielding a different number of permissible floating point values within different ranges (e.g. more possible valid floating point values in [0,1] than in [5,10], assuming the same precision), it can be true about psuedorandom numbers generated by the computer.

Here is a good reference discussing some of this: < http://engineering.medallia.com/blog/2014/08/a-plea-for-an-equal-opportunity-random/ >.

Answer (score -1):

I'd add this question in the comments however I don't yet have enough points to add comments - Why are you trying to find the entropy in a random number?

In order to answer your question, lets look at what a random number actually is and how it's generated in the first place. I found this reference just to give some background: http://computer.howstuffworks.com/question697.htm

Essentially I think entropy depends more-so on the source of your original random number. It can be random due to some effect of nature or it can be pseudo-random where nobody really knows the algorithm that created it and therefore has great difficulty in reproducing the string.

You could argue that if one can understand the source of the random number at a deep enough level, then entropy could essentially be reduced to near-zero. Are you using an entropy formula? Here is one: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Entropy.html.

Your intuition may be telling you that entropy reduces if you perform operations on the source random number because it involves understanding the source better. By this I simply mean you are adding known steps to the equation - which you can back-trace to the source.

I believe as in all things it depends on the **context** - I highly doubt you will find an infinitely precise random number in this universe.

Hope this adds some perspective.

Comment: Why a negative 1 on this?